# Sass (source maps) support in Firefox Developer Tools

Tags: firefox, sass, firefox-developer-tools

With the release of **Firefox 25** we saw a huge improvement in their development tools. SO much so that I'm rather excited to try them out over Firebug.

However I can't see how to turn on Sass debugging, which is currently working in Firebug. I've looked in all the settings that are offered within the development settings.

[image: asdf]

I'm hoping I'm wrong and it is currently supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Firefox 29 the support for Sass and LESS files was introduced.
Taken from https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/02/live-editing-sass-and-less-in-the-firefox-developer-tools/

You have to right-click in the Rules section and activate *Show original sources* option:
[image: Sass/LESS live editing in Firefox Developer Tools]

> Now CSS rule links will show the location in the original file, and
>   clicking these links will take you to the source in the Style Editor.

[image: Sass/LESS live editing showing link to original source Sass/LESS file]

From there you can go on to the Styles Editor and edit your Sass/LESS file. Functionality needs **Source Maps enabled**!

Comment: Took them a year :p Now I need sourcemaps for JS :p

Answer (score 0):

The best suitable way to debug Sass in Firefox seems to be FireSass.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firesass-for-firebug/

Comment: There seems to be a successor called FireCompass. See https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firecompass-for-firebug/